# How is a Buddha able to do things beyond the laws of cause-and-effect?

Tags: mahayana, psychic-powers

A Buddha/Bodhisattva is one who has Awakened and is free from some basic laws of the universe such as karma, reincarnation, the fetters, and various other afflictions.

*In the sutras, such as the Surangama Sutra and Diamond Sutra, such Ones are also able to manifest many other effects -- well beyond **beyond cause-and-effect**, able to shape shift, squeeze thousands of beings into a small house, etc.*

This is understandable considering that a One is already beyond cause-and-effect and thus would be able to manifest such things skillfully and according to needs.

**So my question is... how is this possible?**

According to my teacher, it is the transformation of the aggregates including form and volition... it is still within realm of cause-and-effect... a Buddha is not free from *all* laws of cause-and-effect.
I'd like to know what others know about this rather unimportant topic.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like it might be one of the [Four Unconjecturables](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.077.than.html).

> "There are these four unconjecturables that are not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about them. Which four?
>
> "The Buddha-range of the Buddhas[ 1 ] is an unconjecturable that is not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about it.
>
> "The jhana-range of a person in jhana...[ 2 ]
>
> "The [precise working out of the] results of kamma...
>
> "Conjecture about [the origin, etc., of] the world is an unconjecturable that is not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about it.
>
> "These are the four unconjecturables that are not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about them."
>
> Notes
>
> 1.
>   I.e., the range of powers a Buddha develops as a result of becoming a Buddha.
>
> 2.
>   I.e., the range of powers that one may obtain while absorbed in jhana.

But that is an interesting question. :)

Comment: Thank you This is correct but i will wait for some Abhidharma answer before selecting this one..

Comment: (not @Robin111, but (at)Thanissaro Bhikkhu) That's wrong... How can a quote be opened but not closed ? That makes me uneased. There a no quote in the text from which it was translated http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sltp/AN_II_utf8.html#pts.080

Comment: @Danielson [When to Use Closing Quotes](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/222008/9548) and [How should I use quotation marks in sections of multiline dialogue?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2288/9548)

Comment: @ChrisW thanks for the reference! Obviously my brain is wrong - tough luck. I hope I can get over myself. Or change the English language in favour of my brains :p

Answer (score 1):

> A Buddha/Bodhisattva is one who has Awakened and is free from some basic laws of the universe such as karma

This is not the case. The reason a Buddha has to continue to live out the remainder of his human life despite being enlightened is due to the weight of his karma that brought about the final human existence.

As for how it is possible? It is possible because such is the power of a developed mind. Just as it is possible for a child that has learned to walk to be able to walk, as the body is capable of such, so is it possible for the mind to interact with reality in this way.

[The Fruits of the Contemplative Life](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html)

Comment: Buddhas remain because of their 1st vow.. "I will save all beings and will not enter Nirvana until all beings are saved".. Also the other vows

Comment: thats my fault then, i failed to see the Mahayana tag on your question; disregard.

Comment: I actually didn't put the Mahayana tag and this might be a different question entirely but in Theravada is Buddhahood and Arhathood the same thing? Also, both supposedly go into some sort of extinction right, a 9th samadhi?

Comment: A Buddha in the Theravada is self enlightened and has unobstructed knowledge of whatever he wants to know. An Arahant becomes enlightened under the teaching of a Buddha. The 9th samadi is the cessation of feelings and perceptions.

Comment: Also, in the Theravada, upon death, the Buddha enters into parinirvana, an unconditioned state of being. In Mahayana the claim is made that a Buddha exists eternally.